# Ist dieser Satz korrekt geschrieben?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

Ist dieser Satz korrekt geschrieben?

Die ganze tschechische pädagogische Gesellschaft sucht intensiv nach dem richtigen Weg zur Integration von Migranten, aber auch von anderen Schülern mit Behinderung.

Gibt es bessere Ausdrücke?

Answer (score 3):

> Die ganze tschechische pädagogische Gesellschaft sucht …

Eine *tschechische pädagogische Gesellschaft* ist ein tschechischer Verein, der sich mit Pädagogik befasst. Und mit *die ganze* sind dann alle Mitglieder dieses Vereins gemeint.

Du meinst aber stattdessen sicher alle Pädagogen des Landes, egal ob sie in einem Verein für Pädagogik drin sind oder nicht:

> Alle Pädagogen der tschechischen Gesellschaft suchen …

Weiterhin kannst du in

> … intensiv nach dem richtigen Weg zur Integration von Migranten, aber auch von anderen Schülern mit Behinderung.

nicht das Wort *anderen* verwenden, denn es impliziert im beleidigenden Sinne, dass Migrant zu sein eine Art Behinderung darstelle. Lass es einfach weg:

> … intensiv nach dem richtigen Weg zur Integration von Migranten, aber auch von Schülern mit Behinderung.

Comment: Daran bist Du Schuld: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40171/ist-dieser-satz-korrekt